# Arithmetic and Geometric Sequences (with already-known ratio/difference)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Arithmetic sequence: common difference = $10$
Geometric sequence:  common ratio = $2$

Arithmetic:
$f(1) = 50$
$f(2) = 60$
$f(3) = 70$
$f(4) = 80$

Geometric:
$f(1) = 1$
$f(2) = 2$
$f(3) = 4$
$f(4) = 8$

For each sequence, what is $f(100)$ and how did you get that?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for $f(100)$ is a red herring -- what you're *really* being asked to do is to either find a formula for $f(n)$, or demonstrate an approach to the problem that could be used to find $f(n)$ even if you only happened to compute $f(100)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  For an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), the general term is $a+nd$, where $a$ is the first term and $d$ is the difference.  So plug in $99$ (because I started counting at $n=0$)

For a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), the general term is $ar^n$, where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the ratio between neighboring terms.  Again, plug in $n=99$

Answer (score 1):

For your arithmetic series:

$$ f_a(n) = 40 + 10n \\
f_a(100) = 40 + 10\times100 = 1040 $$

For the geometric series:

$$ f_g(n) = 2^{n-1} \\
f_g(100) = 2^{100-1} = 2^{99} $$

Answer (score 0):

For variety, I'm going to solve this problem the 'wrong' way that demonstrates a useful idea. (I say it's the 'wrong' way, because the intent of this exercise is to develop/demonstrate basic capability with formulas for arithmetic and geometric series)

For the second sequence, you multiply by $2$ every step.

So every $2$ steps, you multiply by $2$ then by $2$ again: you multiply by $4$.

If you take 2 steps then another 2 steps, you see that every 4 steps you multiply by $4$ then $4$ again: you multiply by $16$.

If you take $8$ steps, you multiply by $16^2 = 256$

If you take $16$ steps, you multiply by $256^2 = 65536$

If you take $32$ steps, you multiply by $4294967296$

If you take $64$ steps, you multiply by $18446744073709551616$

You can take $99$ steps by taking $64$ steps then $32$ steps then $2$ steps then $1$ step. Doing so you multiply by

$$ 18446744073709551616 \cdot 4294967296 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 633825300114114700748351602688 $$

So $f(100)$ is $99$ steps from $f(1)$, so

$$ f(100) = f(1) \cdot 633825300114114700748351602688 = 633825300114114700748351602688$$